# Unit tests for math equations

Tags: unit-testing, math, equations

I need to generate unit tests for a mathematical equation such as a= (b+c)* d and boolean expressions.Is there any methodology and/or utility to achieve this?

Comment: I'm sure there is.. but StackOverflow isn't a place for such a general shopping query.

Comment: Start here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Comment: What do you want to test about these equations ? That they parse correctly ? That they evaluate correctly ? Symbolic transformations ? ...

Comment: These are requirements. need to black box test the code written against them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**

Because of the vagueness of the question i'm going to assume the programming language one can use is variable. In this case Python uses a object oriented approach to unittesting.

**Answer:**

For most unittest problems in python, you can use the standard unittest library. An example case for the given equation can be:

```
import unittest

def test_equation(b,c,d):
    return (b+c) * d

class testEquation(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def testEquationInput(self):
        b = 5
        c = 4
        d = 10
        self.assertEqual(test_equation(b,c,d), 90)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

you can execute this code with:

```
python unittest test_module.py
```

or if you write a directory with unittests:

```
python -m unittest discover /path/to/test/directory
```